# Python: how to get a direct Google docs url after uploading to Google drive?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api, google-docs-api, google-api-python-client

I want to upload a text file `.txt` to Google drive and be able to get a direct link where I can edit it directly, so I've written this method

```
def upload(self, file_name, filepath, folder_id, file_id=None, mimeType='text/plain'):

media = MediaFileUpload(
    filepath, mimetype=mimeType, resumable=True)
try:
    if file_id is None:
        file_metadata = {"name": file_name,
                            "parents": [folder_id]
                            }
        file = self.drive.files().create(
            body=file_metadata,
            media_body=media, fields='id').execute()
        file_id = file.get('id')
    else:
        file_metadata = {"name": file_name}
        self.drive.files().update(
            body=file_metadata, removeParents='root',
            media_body=media, fileId=file_id).execute()
    url = 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=' + file_id

    return file_name, file_id, url
```

It's returning a URL that takes you to a document viewer and then you have to click "open with Google docs"

[image]

But I want to get a direct link that opens with Google docs, but the URL of google docs is totally different than what I see in google drive.

Is it possible to get a direct Url to google docs after uploading a file to Google drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you uploading the file as `mimeType='text/plain'` this is not a Google Drive mimetype.  There is a list of [mimetypes](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/mime-types) that are supported.

To covert your .txt file to a google docs file you would need to supply the mimetype to covert it to in the file metadata.  You are not supplying a mimetype in the metadata so the file is not being coverted.

```
file_metadata = {
        "name": file_name,
        "parents": [folder_id]
        'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'
    }
```

Once converted the file should then open in Google docs.

Comment: I tried using `application/vnd.google-apps.document` but I get this error `invalidContentType, message: Invalid MIME type provided for the uploaded content.`

Comment: Is there any way to get it to work without converting .txt to .docx? I don't want to work with [Google docs API](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/move-text) because I don't want to bother with the index being used. I don't know how the index should be used

Comment: I ended up writing directly to google drive via the official API and didn't use the google drive API.  Accepting the answer just to close the question but I didn't use it.

Regarding the index, I just supplied `'index': 1` and wrote the text

Comment: come to think of it I have never tried to convert a .txt to doc maybe it needs to be .docx

Comment: tried docx, not doc, since the latter is deprecated. Maybe it will work with doc, I didn't try, but docx didn't work. Luckily the official API was easy to implement, otherwise, I would have had to find a library to do the conversion. - And sorry I meant to say that I ended up using Google docs API not google drive